# Grepping for 2 column, but there may be spaces in first column

Tags: regex, unix, grep

I have a list...

```
Group Chl# Code Name TMS ID Entitled
SPP Basic 1 VOD Charter On Demand 32046 true
Stream 2 KTVI KTVI 10750 true
Stream 4 KMOV KMOV 10575 true
Stream 5 KSDK KSDK 10685 true
Stream 6 SLATE VideoSlate 0 true
Stream 7 ION WRBU 11530 true
Stream 9 KETC KETC 10443 true
Stream 13 DAYSTAR WPXS Daystar Television 11337 true
Stream 14 SLATE VideoSlate 0 true
Tier 2 15 NFL NFL Network 34710 true
Stream 16 CSPAN CSPAN (Cable Satellite Public Affairs Network) 10161 true
Stream 17 UNI Univision Network (East) 11118 false
Tier 1 18 SECN SEC Network 89535 true
...
Select 104 HILLSNG The Hillsong Channel 29328 true
SPP Tier 1 106 BYUTV BYU - TV 21855 true
Tier 1 107 COWBOY The Cowboy Channel 10188 true
...
Tier 1 121 TNCK Nick - TeenNick 59036 true
SPP Tier 2 122 CI Crime and Investigation Network 48543 true
Tier 2 123 SMITH Smithsonian Channel 65799 true
...
Stream Sports, News & More 806 NBCSNHD NBC Sports Network HDTV 48639 true
SPP Tier 1 807 OLYHD Olympic Channel HDTV 104089 true
Select 809 GLFHD Golf Channel HDTV 61854 true
Tier 2 810 TNNSHD Tennis Channel HDTV 60316 true
Stream Sports, News & More 811 FS1HD Fox Sports 1 HD 82547 true
```

If I grep for a number, I need it to match in the `Chl#` column.

For example, if I `grep 121` in that data, it should return

```
Tier 1 121 TNCK Nick - TeenNick 59036 true
```

If I grep 122, it should return

```
SPP Tier 2 122 CI Crime and Investigation Network 48543 true
```

Version:

```
$ grep -V
GNU grep 2.6.3
```

This grep doesn't seem to recognize REGEXs like this:

```
(?=x)d
```

which means match `d` only if preceded by `x`, but don't include `x`.

When I get a match, I am interested in the last field, true or false.

I can easily get that with awk: `{print $NF}`. Using `grep` isn't a requirement. I would prefer to use `sed`, `grep` and/or `awk`. But not `perl`.

The first column can have 0, 1 or more spaces. It can have a number, a comma.

The second column is a number with 1 to 4 digits.

The third column is a single word.

The fourth column can have multiple spaces.

The fifth is a number with 1 or more digits.

And the sixth is "true" or "false".

I've been playing with this for several hours. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Does your `grep` support the `-P` option to get PCRE? That will provide lookarounds.

Comment: Also, it should be `($<x)` to get a lookbehind, not `($=x)`

Comment: What is the delimiter between columns? If the delimiter is space, and the first column can also contain spaces, how do you know where the first column ends?

Comment: Ues. it's a space. That's the challenge, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it's practically insoluble. If you were doing it by hand, how would you know if the number is part of the Group name or is the `Chl#`?

Comment: I came up with this:

`'^.*[[:space:]][0-9]\{1,4\}[[:space:]].*[[:space:]].*[[:space:]][a-z]\{4,5\}[[:space:]]$'`

There is a space after the "true"|"false".

And I can put a number where "[0-9]\{1,4\}" is. And it will match. But I haven't tried it when there is a number before or after that field.

Comment: Is there any kind of structure to the first column that allows you to tell how many words it contains? Like `Tier` is always followed by a single number?

Comment: That doesn't look promising. Sometimes `Stream` is by itself, other times it's just the first word of `Stream Sports, News & More`.

Comment: If you can't describe the layout unambiguously, you can't program a computer to parse it.

Comment: Perhaps I can pre-process the data with sed, substituting "Tier [123]" with just "Tier":

sed 's/Tier [[:digit:]]/Tier/'

Comment: How would that help if the first column contained something like `Stream 1`?

Comment: Can the word in the third column contain numbers? Can it start with a number?

Comment: I didn't see "Stream" followed by a number unless that number was in the "Chl#" column.

Third column can start with a number.

Comment: I'm not making any assumptions about the data other than what you've stated explicitly. Just because you don't show `Stream` followed by a number in your examples doesn't mean it can't happen.

Comment: You specifically said that the first column can contain numbers. You didn't say this only happens when the first word is `Tier`.

Comment: That's the case in the set of data with which I am testing. There are other sets. And I don't know if they have numerals in the first column or not.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following regexp describes your data:

```
^.* \d{1,4} \w+ .* \d+ (?:true|false)$
```

The number you want to search for replaces `\d{1,4}` in the regexp. You can use the `-P` option to GNU `grep` to get PCRE. Unfortunately, you can't use a lookbehind for this, because lookbehinds have to be fixed-length, they can't contain `.*`. So you can use this to match the whole line, then use something else to extract the last column.

```
grep -P '^.*? 121 \w+ .* \d+ (?:true|false)$' filename | awk '{print $NF}`
```

False positives may still be possible with this, because the first and fourth columns can contain any number of words. If there are any constraints you can provide for some of the other columns (particularly column 3) they can make it better.

Comment: It's close. Is there a way to make the first regex ( `.*`) not greedy? Because it's picking up a number in one of the following columns. For example, searching for "2":

` $ cat 00000736e9a9.ins|sed 's/Tier [[:digit:]]/Tier/'|grep -P '^.* 2 \w+ .* \d+ (?:true|false)\s$'
Stream 2 KTVI KTVI 10750 true
Tier 114 NICK 2 Nickelodeon Too 37551 true
HBO/Cinemax 503 HBO2HD HBO 2 HDTV (East) 59368 false
HBO/Cinemax 504 HBO2HW HBO 2 HDTV (West) 59355 false
Showtime/TMC 563 SHO2HD Showtime 2 HDTV (East) 58533 false
Showtime/TMC 564 SHO2HW Showtime 2 HDTV (West) 60953 false`

Comment: Use `.*?` to make it non-greedy. But if `121` appears in the first column, it might still match.